# deactivate blue border from first row when table view is focused

Tags: css, javafx

I would like to deactivate in javafx showing the blue border in the first row when The table view is focused(see picture). I tried a lot of things in my css without success. I also did't find helpfull contribution here in the Forum.

thx in advance

[image]

Comment: `table tbody tr:first-child:focus { border: transparent }`

Comment: @Morpheus this isn't a html question. Your css won't work for JavaFX.

Comment: @fabian solution should be similar, I believe it is easy to transform to JavaFX.

Comment: @Morpheus okay - then do it :)

Comment: @Morpheus The default stylesheet in JavaFX doesn't use a border setting for table rows. It uses a different technique entirely to create the effect of the border... So even "translating" your web CSS to JavaFX CSS wouldn't have any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me:

```css
.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
}
```

---

Explanation:

The [default stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) has the following CSS rule for focused, non-selected rows:

```css
/* focused cell (keyboard navigation) */
.table-view:focused:row-selection > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}
```

This works by drawing three backgrounds with three different insets (a technique called "nested backgrounds"). The first has insets of 0 (fills the whole row) and is in the default background color (`-fx-background`). The second has insets of 1 (so one pixel of the previous background is left visible); it fills a rectangle with the looked-up color `-fx-cell-focus-inner-border`. The third has insets of 2 (so it leaves one pixel of the middle background visible) and again has the default color.

The default row background is defined by

```css
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}
```

This again uses "nested backgrounds", with the first having zero insets and a background color of `-fx-table-cell-border-color`, and the second having the default background and insets of one pixel along the bottom edge only. So the effect here is a 1-pixel wide bottom border.

The CSS I used above just redefines the focused row to look like the non-focused row.